# Bazel: How to access workspace status variables in Skylark?

Tags: bazel

I'm using the [`--workspace_status_command`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#build-options) with stable status variables similarly to the [Kubernetes test-infra usage](https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra/blob/1904bd3f7e09d56f3661803961443c60bebde710/hack/print-workspace-status.sh#L25:L30).

I would like to expose the `STABLE_*` variables to custom Skylark rules. How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rules_docker` supports stamping from the workspace status files.  It looks like it uses `ctx.info_file` and `ctx.version_file` to access them: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/4d8ec6570a5313fb0128e2354f2bc4323685282a/container/layer_tools.bzl#L83

They aren't in the published docs but the Bazel source code seems to show that those are the right thing: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/0.12.0/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/skylark/SkylarkRuleContext.java#L987-L1011